# How we can return Task<HttpResponseMessage> return type to HttpResponseMessage type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way where we can return TaskHttpResponseMessage type to HttpResponseMessage type?Below is the code.

```
  private HttpResponseMessage Process(string receiver,HttpRequestMessage request)
       {
              Reciever test = new Reciever();
              Task<HttpResponseMessage> res= test.ReceiveAsync(receiver, request);
               return res;      
        }
```

Actually my **ReceiveAsync** method is of **async** type and i dont want **Process** Method to be of **async** type.

Any idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you've ruled out the right answer (*"i dont want Process Method to be of async type."*) you really need to justify why this isn't an appropriate fix

Comment: If you insist you could just do res.Result but it's considered a bad practice. Microsoft recommends using await/async "all the way down" if possible.

Comment: To add to spender's comment, why does the underlying work you're doing need to be an asynchronous operation?  If you want synchronous code, that's fine, but make it synchronous through and through.

Answer (score -1):

this could work i think:

EDIT: Don't do this, as it will deadlock - thanks @Servy

```
private HttpResponseMessage Process(string receiver, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return ProcessAsync(receiver, request).Result;
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessAsync(string receiver, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    Reciever test = new Reciever();
    var  res = await test.ReceiveAsync(receiver, request);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use async/await "all the way down" rather than using ProcessAsync.Result. I suppose the OP did ask for something like this though..

Comment: I totally agree with the async/await all the way. i would never do it like this, but it is what he is asking, and it will work.

Comment: This code will deadlock anytime there is a synchronization context.

Comment: @PawOrmstrupMadsen Except in all of the situations where it won't work, which is most of the time.

Comment: Would this make any thing better? return ProcessAsync(receiver, request).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); I've never tried that approach before, might be because i don't do a lot of sync stuff,